# XSLT Transformation - recurring structure results in summary of values

Tags: xml, xslt

I need help with another issue in my XSLT-Transformation.

I have some recurring structure in my input file with different values.

```
                <Dbtr>
                    <Nm>TEST BANK GMBH</Nm>
                </Dbtr>
                <DbtrAcct>
                    <Id>
                        <IBAN>DE07702203005401252462</IBAN>
                    </Id>
                </DbtrAcct>
                <DbtrAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BIC>TESTBDEM0XXX</BIC>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </DbtrAgt>
                <CdtrAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BIC>HYVEDEMM475</BIC>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </CdtrAgt>
                <Cdtr>
                    <Nm>Name 1</Nm>
                </Cdtr>
                <CdtrAcct>
                    <Id>
                        <IBAN>DE92660202860002099551</IBAN>
                    </Id>
                </CdtrAcct>
                <Dbtr>
                    <Nm>Name 2</Nm>
                </Dbtr>
                <DbtrAcct>
                    <Id>
                        <IBAN>DE88702203005002522901</IBAN>
                    </Id>
                </DbtrAcct>
                <DbtrAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BIC>TESTBDEM0XXX</BIC>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </DbtrAgt>
                <CdtrAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BIC>HYVEDEMMXXX</BIC>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </CdtrAgt>
                <Cdtr>
                    <Nm>FIRMA X</Nm>
                </Cdtr>
                <CdtrAcct>
                    <Id>
                        <IBAN>DE39700202704320253727</IBAN>
                    </Id>
                </CdtrAcct>
```

This is some part of the XSLT-File:

```
                        <OrgnlTxRef>
                            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                                <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$_find_amount"/>
                                </IntrBkSttlmAmt>
                                <IntrBkSttlmDt>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="//myTxNS:TxInfAndSts/myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:IntrBkSttlmDt[not(.=preceding::*)]">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </IntrBkSttlmDt>
                                <DbtrAgt>
                                    <FinInstnId>
                                        <BIC>TESTBDEM0XXX</BIC>
                                    </FinInstnId>
                                </DbtrAgt>
                                <CdtrAgt>
                                    <FinInstnId>
                                        <BIC>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="//myTxNS:TxInfAndSts/myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:CdtrAgt/myTxNS:FinInstnId/myTxNS:BIC">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                        </BIC>
                                    </FinInstnId>
                                </CdtrAgt>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="position()=2">
                                <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$_find_amount2"/>
                                </IntrBkSttlmAmt>
                                <IntrBkSttlmDt>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="//myTxNS:TxInfAndSts/myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:IntrBkSttlmDt[not(.=preceding::*)]">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </IntrBkSttlmDt>
                                <DbtrAgt>
                                    <FinInstnId>
                                        <BIC>TESTBDEM0XXX</BIC>
                                    </FinInstnId>
                                </DbtrAgt>
                                <CdtrAgt>
                                    <FinInstnId>
                                        <BIC>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="//myTxNS:TxInfAndSts/myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:CdtrAgt/myTxNS:FinInstnId/myTxNS:BIC">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                        </BIC>
                                    </FinInstnId>
                                </CdtrAgt>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </OrgnlTxRef>
```

My actual result was:

```
         <OrgnlTxRef>
            <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">8.28</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
            <IntrBkSttlmDt>2017-10-26</IntrBkSttlmDt>
            <DbtrAgt>
               <FinInstnId>
                  <BIC>TESTBDEM0XXX</BIC>
               </FinInstnId>
            </DbtrAgt>
            <CdtrAgt>
               <FinInstnId>
                  <BIC>HYVEDEMM475HYVEDEMMXXX</BIC>
               </FinInstnId>
            </CdtrAgt>

            <DbtrAgt>
               <FinInstnId>
                  <BIC>TESTBDEM0XXX</BIC>
               </FinInstnId>
            </DbtrAgt>
            <CdtrAgt>
               <FinInstnId>
                  <BIC>HYVEDEMM475HYVEDEMMXXX</BIC>
               </FinInstnId>
            </CdtrAgt>
         </OrgnlTxRef>
      </TxInfAndSts>
   </nsC:FIToFIPmtStsRptSCL>
</nsC:BBkRSFBlkDirDeb>
```

I need something to avoid this:

```
           <FinInstnId>
              <BIC>HYVEDEMM475HYVEDEMMXXX</BIC>
           </FinInstnId>
```

and have a clear result like this:

```
...
           <FinInstnId>
              <BIC>HYVEDEMMXXX</BIC>
           </FinInstnId>
...
...
           <FinInstnId>
              <BIC>HYVEDEMM475</BIC>
           </FinInstnId>
...
```

I searched this page and try different "ideas" how to solve that problem. But i get always the same result of combined values in the output file.

Comment: Consider to post minimal samples to demonstrate the specific problem of the question, there is just too much data in there to tell where you need to fix the code or the approach.

Comment: Thanks. I snip it up to the relevant content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with these lines

```
<BIC>
   <xsl:for-each select="//myTxNS:TxInfAndSts/myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:CdtrAgt/myTxNS:FinInstnId/myTxNS:BIC">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each>
</BIC>
```

Firstly, when you start an expression with `//`, this will start the search at the document node, and look for elements anywhere in the XML. I am guessing what you want is to select only elements relative to the current node you are on.

I think you have snipped too much off your XSLT, but I think at the point this code runs you are positioned on an `myTxNS:TxInfAndSts` element, and so the expression should really be just this.

```
<xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:CdtrAgt/myTxNS:FinInstnId/myTxNS:BIC">
```

Also, you possibly want to move the creation of the `<BIC>` tag inside the `xsl:for-each`.

```
<xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:CdtrAgt/myTxNS:FinInstnId/myTxNS:BIC">
    <BIC>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </BIC>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ... it works perfect. 
If you are in the near of Munich/Germany i stand you one or more beer ;)